# How to stop auto play of embedded video?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, autoplay

Here is a video clip from metacafe.com that I am trying to embed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<iframe 
width="720" height="405" 
src="http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4$autoStart=false" 
frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Embedding is okay, except the clip starts playing automatically once the page is loaded. How can I stop the autoplay here?

I tried the following options, but none of them worked:

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**/&autoStart=false**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**/&autoStart=0**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**/?autoStart=false**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**/?autoStart=0**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**&autoStart=false**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**&autoStart=0**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**?autoStart=false**

http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11600739/natasha-the-founder-of-easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy-forms-the-secrets-to-form-a-saas-application-mp4**?autoStart=0**

I also tried using **autoPlay** instead of **autoStart** in all these options, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Who voted for this question to be closed? Why?

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have as the source for the iFrame is a link to a web page, not to a video.

You can see this by loading the link in a browser and then 'inspecting' the page with developer tools.

That web page then contains the link to video itself and a player, which has autoplay set so the video starts immediately.

If you have access to the video link then you may find it easier to add it to your own page - the video looks like at least one version of it is a HLS file so you will need either a JavaScript web player or a browser which supports HLS natively - using a player is safer as it offer wider support.

Comment: Thank you so much. At least, now I know where the problem is!

Comment: I should have mentioned also that the video links are in the iframe 'page' also - you can see them in the page source when you use the inspector tools on the iframe itself. The HLS video link (the one ending in .m3u8) will play in any javascript player which supports HLS and will play natively in some browsers such as safari on a Mac (paste the URL ending in m3u8 into the browser bar directly to test).